# How to implement root route and get "index" to the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I want all of the following URL works

- localhost:3000 (in real world, www.example.com)
- localhost:3000/index (in real world, www.example.com/index)
- localhost:3000/home (in real world, www.example.com/home)

These URLs will route to the same location - index.html.erb. In other words, the same controller's same action (static_pages#index).

I know this problem can be solved as the following:

```
root "static_pages#index"
get "index" => "static_pages#index", :as => :index
get "home" => "static_pages#index", :as => :home
```

The short question is "Is there a way to implement these routes in one coding sentence, or in more efficient and effective way?"

Comment: I think this communicates the situation nicely to the reader (which could be you in the future), why do you want to make it more efficient?

Comment: What's wrong with doing it like this?

Comment: I think a little bit code duplication occur and not so rails alike (I means not so beautiful code).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution that implies more than one line, is using scope to make it cleaner, you will have two extra lines of code, but I found it more readable:

```
scope :path => '/', :controller => :static_pages do
  get 'index' => :index, :as => 'index'
  get 'home' => :index, :as => 'home'
end
```

That way you make explicit which controller to use for all routes + the path (first part of it).

Comment: thanks for answer. I accept it looks more rails alike but the root_path or root_url don't work anymore.

Comment: You can add `root to: 'static_pages#index'` inside or outside your scope. It's a possible solution and maybe doesn't fit what you expect, cause it takes more code to solve the problem.